# JSONata recursive mapping

Tags: jsonata

I am trying to perform recursive mapping.

Here's my example: https://try.jsonata.org/jN2b0Pt2t

I am, in this simple reproducer, trying to re-map the original "Person" with "Name", "Age" and "Parent" to just "n" and "p" (representing the mapped "Name" and "Parent").

I cannot figure out why this does not work.

If I use `$person($v)` in the `$map(..)` function I get a stack overflow error so I know the recursion is happening!

Any help appreciated.

Thank-you,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The issue was all mine; the following mapping works OK:

```
(
    $person := function($node) {
        $node ~> $map(function($v, $i) {
            {"n":$v.Name, "p":$person($v.Parent.Person)}
        })
    };

{
    "Person": Person ~> $person($)
}
)
```

Comment: Just to simplify slightly, you don't need to use the `$map` function explicitly, you can use the map operator `.` in your function:
`$person := function($node) { $node.{"n": Name, "p":$person(Parent.Person)}`